# using jQuery $(this) within Bootstrap modal to refer to modal target

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a dynamic number of buttons with class `.btn-trash.` I execute some code on click of any of these buttons based on it's position in the dom, using `$(this)`. I would like to modify this to open a Bootstrap confirmation modal window on click of that same button, and execute the same code on confirmation of this modal. I can no longer use `$(this)` as I am not in the context of where `.btn-trash` is in the dom, but in the context of the new confirm button in my modal. I'm having trouble now figuring out which `.btn-trash` was clicked, in order to perform my logic. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btnblue btn-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">
    <span class="glyphicon icon-trash"></span>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer text-left">
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-delete-plan" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-trash', function () {
    //moved initial logic from here to '.btn-delete-plan' click
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-plan', function () {
    //target the '.btn-trash' that was initially clicked and execute code
    //based on its position in the dom
});
```

Comment: save the reference `var me = $(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jasen said just save a reference in your .btn-trash click handler.

```
var $lastClicked; 
$(document).on('click', '.btn-trash', function () {
    $lastClicked = $(this);
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-plan', function () {
    //use $lastClicked
});
```